# No chaincode found on peer after installation through peer lifecycle

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, lifecycle, invoke, peer

I follow by instruction from the fabric-sample/test-network, but trying to reproduce steps of control in docker container. All steps of chaincode installation went good except one of the final - `peer chaincode invoke`.

On this step I got an error: `2020-07-09 10:40:00.755 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> DEBU 05a ESCC invoke result: response:<status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel appchannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'fabcar' exists, but chaincode is not installed" >  Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel appchannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'fabcar' exists, but chaincode is not installed"`

When I check chaincode with `peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled` I receive a normal response:
`Installed chaincodes on peer: Package ID: fabcar_1:644530ed4e097a65073d6e0fc8a7aaa9282945e55aa1ec7d2014746fd598f631, Label: fabcar_1`

But when I check chaincode with `peer chaincode list --installed` I receive empty set:
`Get installed chaincodes on peer:`

configtx.yaml from test-example is used.

Where is my mistake?

[Here is my Dockerfile.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k-2fAo3z6sXSq5TuMpHQCdYJGvPzDObU/view?usp=sharing) The main idea is to make a self-sufficient docker environment of hyperledger with outscripting needs.

Comment: Can you please share the commands used for `install` and `invoke`? Also, please check that the `peer` is same  when `installing` and `invoking` chaincode.

Comment: @alpha I've attached to the question

Answer (score 1):

The command `peer chaincode ...` use the LSCC - Lifecycle System Chaincode, which is used for the 1.x Fabric network. The 2.x docs about this [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/smartcontract/smartcontract.html?highlight=lscc#system-chaincode)

You can try using the old-style command to install chaincode `peer chaincode install ...`, then you can query the installed chaincode with `peer chaincode list --installed`. But from version 2.0, it's recommended using the new lifecycle chaincode.

I also found the in-practice chaincode comparison of version 1.4 and 2.0 [here](https://medium.com/@kctheservant/chaincode-container-comparison-between-fabric-v1-4-and-v2-0-50a835aaad6a). Hope this can give you some ideas.

Comment: I'm ready to use a new api, but where `invoke` analogue there?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @HoaiNam that you have to use `fabricv2.x` api's since you are using `test-network`. Also you can try previous command by adding `v1.4.x` capabilities(not sure). for understanding latest CC lifecycle process, you can refer [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/chaincode_lifecycle.html). for commands, you can refer to `test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Of course I'm going step by step of *sh scripts, have several rounds of checks where is difference - bat can't find. But I don't understand main idea. How to find the error? Logs doesn't help. What strings would be in peer logs of success codechain deploying?

Comment: You have to check `orderer`, `peer` and `chaincode(if any)` containers for error.

Comment: But they are not there! Only ordinary warnings

Comment: Is Logging level set to `debug` in compose-files?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it doesn't matter for possible errors.

Comment: Can you try installing CC on every peer then then try invoke command?

Comment: As you can see in attached file firstly I'm trying to install on 2 peers, commits and then call `invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

In the new lifecycle we have to use :

```
peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
```

In the old lifecycle we use

```
peer chaincode list --installed
```